# How can we change the default permissions for files uploaded to our web server?

Tags: web-server, unix, permissions

When a user uploads image files to our website the default permissions result in images which can't be viewed.  How can we change default permissions to `755` automatically when for uploaded images?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `umask` for your web server.  [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428416/setting-the-umask-of-the-apache-user) talks about how that is done for Apache (add a `umask` command to the script(s) that are run to start Apache).